# select the data from any of the four tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to select the data from any of the four tables. Data can be available on any one out of four. Four table also will have data. two table also will have data. one table also will have data. please correct me below.

```
select top 100  t1.* 
from  
Table1 t1 
left JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.EventId = t2.EventId 
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.EventId = t3.EventId
LEFT JOIN Table4 t4 ON t1.EventId = t4.EventId
WHERE 
t1.EventId = 12345 AND 
t1.EditType = 'D' and 
t2.EditType = 'D'and 
t3.EditType = 'D' and 
t4.EditType = 'D'
```

Comment: Do all of those tables have same structure? Your query pulls data only from table 1, Did I understand correctly that you want data from all 4 of tables?

Comment: data can be available any one of the table or all tables or two table or one table. I want to pick that. Tables are having same structure only.

Answer (score 3):

Putting the conditions in the `WHERE` clause turns outer joins into inner joins. Put the conditions in the `ON` clause

```
Select *
from Table1 t1 
left JOIN Table2 t2 
  on t1.EventId = t2.EventId 
  and t2.EditType = 'D'
left  JOIN Table3 t3 
  ON t1.EventId = t3.EventId
  and t3.EditType = 'D' 
left  JOIN Table4 t4 
  ON t1.EventId = t4.EventId
  and t4.EditType = 'D'

where t1.EventId = 12345
and t1.EditType = 'D'
```

Answer (score 2):

If your tables have the same structure, you might be better doing a union all in a view or CTE (common table expression), then selecting from it instead of doing a left join - that way your information is appearing in separate records:

```
WITH FullData AS (
SELECT *, 1 AS TableSource FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 2 AS TableSource FROM Table2
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 3 AS TableSource FROM Table3
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 4 AS TableSource FROM Table4 )
SELECT * FROM FullData WHERE EventID = 12345 And EventType = 'D'
```

As per my example, you can also add in a source identifier to tell which table the information is being pulled from - as long as the structure remains the same throughout, the union all will work fine.